# Concurrently processing data. What do I need to watch out for?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I have a routine that is meant to load and parse data from a file. There is a possibility that the data from the same file might need to be retrieved from two places at once, i.e. during a background caching process and from a user request.

Specifically I am using C++11 thread and mutex libraries. We compile with Visual C++ 11 (aka 2012), so are limited by whatever it lacks.

My naive implementation went something like this:

```
map<wstring,weak_ptr<DataStruct>> data_cache;
mutex data_cache_mutex;

shared_ptr<DataStruct> ParseDataFile(wstring file_path) {
    auto data_ptr = make_shared<DataStruct>();

    /* Parses and processes the data, may take a while */

    return data_ptr;
}

shared_ptr<DataStruct> CreateStructFromData(wstring file_path) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(data_cache_mutex);

    auto cache_iter = data_cache.find(file_path);
    if (cache_iter != end(data_cache)) {
        auto data_ptr = cache_iter->second.lock();
        if (data_ptr)
            return data_ptr;
        // reference died, remove it
        data_cache.erase(cache_iter);
    }

    auto data_ptr = ParseDataFile(file_path);

    if (data_ptr)
        data_cache.emplace(make_pair(file_path, data_ptr));

    return data_ptr;
}
```

My goals were two-fold:

- Allow multiple threads to load separate files concurrently
- Ensure that a file is only processed once

The problem with my current approach is that it doesn't allow concurrent parsing of multiple files at all. If I understand what will happen correctly, they're each going to hit the lock and end up processing linearly, one thread at a time. It may change from run to run the order which the threads pass through the lock first, but the end result is the same.

One solution I've considered was to create a second map:

```
map<wstring,mutex> data_parsing_mutex;

shared_ptr<DataStruct> ParseDataFile(wstring file_path) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(data_parsing_mutex[file_path]);
    /* etc. */
    data_parsing_mutex.erase(file_path);
}
```

But now I have to be concerned with how `data_parsing_mutex` is being updated. So I guess I need another mutex?

```
map<wstring,mutex> data_parsing_mutex;
mutex data_parsing_mutex_mutex;

shared_ptr<DataStruct> ParseDataFile(wstring file_path) {
    unique_lock<mutex> super_lock(data_parsing_mutex_mutex);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(data_parsing_mutex[file_path]);
    super_lock.unlock();

    /* etc. */

    super_lock.lock();
    data_parsing_mutex.erase(file_path);
}
```

In fact, looking at this, it's not going to avoid necessarily double-processing a file if it hasn't been completed by the background process when the user requests it, unless I check the cache yet again.

But by now my spidey senses are saying `There must be a better way`. Is there? Would futures, promises, or atomics help me at all here?

Comment: As I understand, the problem is not in `ParseDataFile()` itself? What is the point of adding mutexes to it, if it's invoked from under another mutex (in `CreateStructFromData()`)

Comment: The second mutex is created and associated with each individual file passed in to `ParseDataFile`. The outer mutex projects the cache while the inner is meant to prevent two threads doing the same work from the same file.

Comment: @MikeE Have you tried using [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) instead of explicit parallelism?

Comment: @Jason I think you have hit the nail on the head for this problem. In my case I would probably use non-deferred asyncs or look into some way to prioritize the asyncs most likely to be needed first. I was unaware of async and haven't used futures before although I had read of their existence. But now I know. :-) Thanks! I'd approve a more fleshed out version of this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, it sounds like you're trying to do a form of lazy initialization of the `DataStruct` using a thread pool, along with a reference counted cache.  `std::async` should be able to provide a lot of the dispatch and synchronization necessary for something like this.

Using `std::async`, the code would look something like this...

```
map<wstring,weak_ptr<DataStruct>> cache;
map<wstring,shared_future<shared_ptr<DataStruct>>> pending;

mutex cache_mutex, pending_mutex;

shared_ptr<DataStruct> ParseDataFromFile(wstring file) {
    auto data_ptr = make_shared<DataStruct>();

    /* Parses and processes the data, may take a while */

    return data_ptr;

}


shared_ptr<DataStruct> CreateStructFromData(wstring file) {
    shared_future<weak_ptr<DataStruct>> pf;
    shared_ptr<DataStruct> ce;

    {
        lock_guard(cache_mutex);

        auto ci = cache.find(file);

        if (!(ci == cache.end() || ci->second.expired()))
          return ci->second.lock();
    }

    {
        lock_guard(pending_mutex);

        auto fi = pending.find(file);

        if (fi == pending.end() || fi.second.get().expired()) {

            pf = async(ParseDataFromFile, file).share();
            pending.insert(fi, make_pair(file, pf));

        } else {

            pf = pi->second;

        }
    }

    pf.wait();
    ce = pf.get();

    {
        lock_guard(cache_mutex);

        auto ci = cache.find(file);

        if (ci == cache.end() || ci->second.expired())
          cache.insert(ci, make_pair(file, ce));
    }

    {
        lock_guard(pending_mutex);

        auto pi = pending.find(file);

        if (pi != pending.end())
          pending.erase(pi);
    }

    return ce;

}
```

This can probably be optimized a bit, but the general idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

On a typical computer there is little point in trying to load files concurrently, since disk access will be the bottleneck. Instead, it's better to have a single thread load files (or use asynchronous I/O) and dish out the parsing to a thread pool. Then store the results in a shared container.

Regarding preventing double work, you should consider if this is really necessary. If you are only doing this out of premature optimization, you'd probably make users happier by focussing on making the program responsive, rather than efficient. That is, make sure the user gets what they ask for quickly, even if it means doing double work.

OTOH, if there is a technical reason for not parsing a file twice, you can keep track of the status of each file (loading, parsing, parsed) in the shared container.

Comment: In this case, it is necessary. The bulk of what this process does is churning over the data after it's read. The bottleneck isn't I/O, which is over almost instantly. I'm implementing this because the delay on switching to another set of data is an issue and it's certainly something which can be done in the background.